# Is C_b((a,b)) a complete metric space?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $C_b((a,b))$ be the space of continuous and bounded functions on $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$, let $||f||_\infty := \sup\{|f(x)| : x \in (a, b)\}$. Is ($C_b((a,b)),||\cdot||_\infty)$ a complete metric space?

I really have no idea how to proceed with this problem...

Sorry for my english skills, english is not my first language...

Comment: What does it mean to be a complete metric space?

Comment: Every cauchy sequence is convergent

Comment: It is complete if every Cauchy sequence converges. So to prove it is complete, you take an arbitrary Cauchy sequence and show it has a limit, IE a function in the space it approaches.  To show it isn't complete, you need to find one cauchy sequence that doesn't converge

Comment: I think is is not a complete metric space, but i cant find any example for it...

Comment: The space you are loking for is $C((a,b))$ or $C([a,b])$?

Comment: It is actually C((a,b))

Comment: The problem is that on $C((a,b))$, $||\cdot||_\infty$ in not a well defined norm, since in could be infinite. You must restrict to the space $C_b(a,b)$ i.e. the space of continuous and bounded function on $(a,b)$, then the answer is affermative, it is a Banach space